# on the automorphisms of the transcendental Hodge structure of a K3 surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, k3-surfaces

Let $S$ be a complex projective K3 surface and consider the sub-Hodge structure
$$
T(S) \subset H^2(S, \mathbb{Q})
$$ consisting of transcendental cycles. Let $\varphi$ be an automorphism of Hodge structures of $T(S)$.

Is it true that $\varphi$ is induced by an automorphism of $S$?

I guess this is the case for the whole $H^2(S, \mathbb{Q})$ (should follow from the Torelli theorem), but what happens when one restricts to $T(S)$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should be related to the problem whether it extend to an automorphism of the whole lattice $H^2(S,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Is such an extension always possible?

Comment: A candidate would be to take an endomorphism $\phi: S\to S$ which is not an automorphism, but whose graph induces a derived autoequivalence. It is a result of Orlov that equivalences of derived categories between K3's will induce Hodge isometries of the transcendental Hodge structure (I had left essentially this comment yesterday, but deleted it because it is not at all obvious to me that such a thing exists).

Comment: What do you allow as an "automorphism"?  Is the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear automorphism that multiplies by $n$ allowed?  Do you want to look only at automorphisms that preserve the Beauville-Bogomolov form / the cup-product pairing?

Comment: I was just thinking of endomorphisms of the $\mathbb{Q}-$Hodge structure $T(S)$. Zarhin proved that the algebra $\mathrm{End}_{Hdg}(T(S))$ is either a totally real field or a CM field. The easiest instance of the later is a cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_d)$. Then you get an endomorphism $\varphi$ of $T(S)$ such that $\varphi^d=Id$. Is this actually induced by a finite order automorphism of the K3?